# Bootstrap navbar transparent on mobile

Tags: html, css, navbar

I've set up my homepage the way I wanted it to look. However, when looking at it on a mobile device, the navbar, which on mobile changes to a dropdown menu, has no background color. I've been trying to change the color itself, but it doesn't do anything.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just give the `.navbar-collapse` a `background` in your css:

```
.navbar-collapse {
   background: #333;
}
```

Comment: Works on mobile now, but makes the whole bar look weird on desktop

Comment: @ChrisTian Okay, target it with a media query for mobile. I should have said that.

Answer (score -1):

I think better will be to use your own css like this:-

```
.navbar-collapse {
   background: #000;
}
```

Answer (score -1):

[image: Where the problem is]

The opacity is set to 0.9

Set it to 1 to be opaque

Answer (score -1):

you can use CSS media queries to set style for mobile view.